# Read access violation when running my program

Tags: c++, memory

I am creating a simple Bank system in c++ to test my knowledge since I'm a beginner.
I am having trouble with writing data to a private class, and after looking around on the internet I came up with a solution that I thought would work but doesn't.
There is an exception thrown when I finish the "Creating a user" part which says "***Exception thrown: read access violation._Pnext was 0x6***". I'm not sure what this means, but my guess is that it has something to do with the pointers in the createuser function.
I hope I'm not too vague in my explanation here, but I have absolutely no idea what is happening. Also, any criticism is welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void clearscreen();
int createuser();
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::string Username;
    std::string Password;
    int money = 0;

public:
    void setUsername(std::string x) {
        Username = x;
    }
    void setPassword(std::string y) {
        Password = y;
    }
    void setMoney(int z) {
        money = z;
    }
};
void clearscreen() {
    system("cls");

}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Welcome new User!\n" << std::endl;
    bool exitprogram = false;
    while (exitprogram == false)
    {
        std::cout << "The Options are:\n";
        std::cout << "1.  Create User\n" << "2.  Login\n" << "3.  Exit Program\n" << "\nEnter an option: ";
        int option = 0;
        std::cin >> option;
        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
            createuser();
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "\nThis option is not avalible yet!";
        case 3:
            exitprogram = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    


    return 0;
}


int createuser() {

    clearscreen();
    MyClass User;
    int* p = (int*)&User;
    std::string* i = (std::string*)&User;
    std::cout << "Please enter the correct information!\n" << "Username: ";
    std::string createusern;
    std::cin >> createusern;
    *i = createusern;
    std::cout << "\n Password: ";
    std::string createpasswordn;
    std::cin >> createpasswordn;
    *i = createpasswordn;
    std::cout << "\nDeposit Money: ";
    int insertmoney;
    std::cin >> insertmoney;
    *p = insertmoney;
    std::cout << "\n\n Congratz, You now have a bank accout! \n\n";
    clearscreen();
    return 0;
     
    
}
```

Comment: There is undefined behavior in the code. I am not sure what you expect to happen. You can't `User` to an int pointer or a string pointer. It's neither of those.

Comment: It means one of your pointers is being misused.   Possibilities include a dangling pointer (that points at something that no longer exists), and uninitialised pointer (so even accessing its value gives undefined behaviour, let alone trying to access what it points at), a null pointer (which points at nothing, by definition), or a pointer that has been forced to point at something that is a different type.   Your code `MyClass User;  int* p = (int*)&User;` is an example of the last particularly since subsequent code uses `p` as if it points at an `int`, when it doesn't.

Comment: `int* p = (int*)&User;` -- Why??  Where would you get the notion that this is valid, let alone try something like this?  If you're a beginner in C++, you should use proper C++ reading material (peer-reviewed books) to learn the language, as C++ is one of the most complex computer languages to learn and learn properly.  There isn't any reputable C++ book that has code similar to what you're attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointer casting is all over the map and certainly "unusual" and incorrect for what you're trying to do.

This line `*i = createusern;` is incorrect because `i` is not pointing to a string. It is pointing to a `User` object. That you really want to do here is something like this

```
User.setUsername( createusern );
```

…and the same goes for your other population attempts. You have setter functions for these elements, so use them.

You should also keep in mind that your `User` object is local and will not survive past the end of the `createuser` function

Answer (score 1):

Well this is definitely wrong:

```
MyClass User;
int* p = (int*)&User;
```

An object of `MyClass` is not an `int`, and yet you are forcing the compiler to set a pointer-to-int to point to it.  That's invoking undefined behavior, which can lead to a crash (as you saw)

```
std::string* i = (std::string*)&User;
```

... same problem here.  An object of `MyClass` is not a `std::string` either, so forcing the compiler to set a pointer-to-string to point to it doesn't make sense either.

I don't know what you're trying to do there, but using C-style casts to force pointers to point to unrelated types is definitely not the way to do it.